# Wcf Request Lifecycle

Tags: .net, wcf

Is there a lifecycle that WCF requests go through?  Specifically I need to be able to intercept and possibly cancel requests made before they get to the method that was invoked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to implement an IDispatchMessageInspector and inject it in the serivce behavior stack.

use IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest to accept or reject a request.

see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx

and

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFIPfilter.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could write your code in

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

OR

```
void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

events in the global.asax on the serverside.